# How to get the background to follow the camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am looking to make the background follow the player instead of having to keep pasting the background across the screen. Do i need to attach the background to do the same?

The code below is the code i have to move the background across the screen

```
using System.Collections;     
using System.Collections.Generic;      
using UnityEngine;

    public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour

{
    private Vector3 xDirectionMove;

        public Transform LevelFinishCam;
        public float speed = 5f;

    void Start()
    {
        xDirectionMove = (LevelFinishCam.position -transform.position).normalized;
    }

    void Update()
{
    transform.position += xDirectionMove * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

}

Comment: Put the background and player in the same control like a panel.  Then move the TOP/LEFT position of player so background doesn't have to move.

Comment: Please don't post an image of your code.  Copy and paste the code so that it is searchable by others.

Comment: assuming its 2d you could just child the background to the camera

Comment: This question is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]. It is also not an appropriate use for the [tag:visual-studio] tag.

Comment: I have child the background to the character however i would like it to be a few z coordinates behind the camera how would i do this? @BugFinder

Comment: so move it back some z.. the child will stay that far behind...

Answer (score 1):

there are some examples in this thread:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1310167/how-to-make-the-background-follow-the-camera.html